# How to format a phone number using regular expression for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I need to save a phone number with Nigeria extension code: +2349026356274 on firebase as user account phoneNumber.

I have a GSM number like this: 09026356274
I use regular expression to format and add the country extension code:

```
var result = "+234"+number.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

I now got result: `+2349026356274`
When i submit the number to firebase, i got this error:
The specified value `"+2349026356274"` is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression:

```
 -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

I do not understand regular expression.

The number was not submitted, what can i do?

Comment: You are trying to save a phone number which is a string (correct) into a field that expects a number (incorrect). Change your phone field to accept strings.

Comment: The clue is in the error "The specified value "+2349026356274" is not a valid number". The regular expression is checking that the value is a valid number (not phone number) and does not allow the number to be prefixed with a `+` character

Comment: You could use this app to get detailed explanation of the regexp https://regex101.com/r/dKIgBU/1/ Though this one is quite simple: it matches positive and negative float numbers possibly in scientific notation. By numbers I meant string representation of a number :).

Comment: Thank you all for the great contributions . My problem has been solved.